# Google Analytics Advanced Filter = ?utm returns a few results

Tags: google-analytics, utm, advanced-filter

I'm trying to figure out why filtering with **?utm** returns a few repetitive results *(specific days and locations, etc)*.

There's no UTMs setup this way (bench?utm_medium) and they all follow the typical convention across our campaigns (...**&utm_medium**=banner).

Could anyone explain why these are filtered and displayed in the results?

[image: Screencap of results]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No prob DalmTo, will close and move to webapps.